# Can body temperature affect the quality of sleep?

Tags: human-biology, sleep

If so, how does it influence our sleep? And what can we do to improve the quality of sleep by adjesting our body tempurature?

Comment: This question is way too broad. If your question is on the last three examples, and on those examples only, it is quite answerable, but rather poorly researched. They look like assumptions - where did you read it?

Comment: @AliceD Our tutor asked us to make a presentation on it. Having searched on the internet, we think these factors *may* have influence on people's quality of sleep, but we are not sure.

Comment: Try sleeping in a noisy floodlit insecure environment, with people stumbling upon you all the time.

Comment: If you can make your question more specific, please do. As of now it would need a uni library to answer. Then a better question would likely be "What does *not* affect sleep?" :)

Comment: @AliceD Like this?

Comment: Awesome. Much better +1

Comment: Might be more on-topic on [health.SE](health.stackexchange.com).